# Storing imagepaths parmanently in android

Tags: android, image, path, storage

User can select images from gallery. So I used this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Each time the user selects image from gallery, I show these selected images in **gridview** in my activity. So, I have number of `imagepaths` of the user selected images. So, how can I store these imagepaths and show these images that are selected previously everytime to user in a gridview. So, I am thinking of to add the imagepaths in arraylist. 
If I use `sqlite` to store these imagepaths, it would be an overkill. I am thinking to make use of `sharedpreference` to save this arraylist.

1)  Is it an efficient way to store? Since the arraylist may contain 100’s of imagepaths. When user reenters, he can add some more pictures and can delete some more pictures.

2)  Addition can be done easily to `arraylist`, but what should be done when he deletes? 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using SQLite with transaction... But why did you say it will be overkill?

EDIT - 
It is a simple code, maybe you can write it and test to make sure it is too heavy or not for your objective.

Example:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for(String it : imgPaths)
    db.insert(it);//You will need to place in a ContentValue
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

And than you clean your table when you need to flush the cache.

Comment: You mean each row for each image? o_O And what the transaction should do here? Can you please brief it more than this?